# two qtableviews, two models and the same data

Tags: c++, qt

I have

- a vector A
- two QTableModel: a and b
- and two QTableView: c and d

a is model of c, b is model of d

the two Models present the same data (A) in two different ways.
The problem is that when I edit data with model a, from view b; view d doesn't changed data (doesn't "update the view") until i click it (when it sets focus).
I emit dataChanged in every setData function in a and b.
Finally I try to connect the datachange signals:

```
QObject::connect(a, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), b, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));
```

This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can't you just have 1 model shared between both views?

Comment: i need two different behavior of data() function. no i can't, I need two model that use the same vector of data

Comment: @Francesco Oh, please, consider _not_ using models that way! Maybe I don't get something, but wouldn't it fit your needs to have 1 model, containing data and two descendants of `QAbstractProxyModel`, connected with it? Those descendants can have their `data()` overriden. That may spare you of hacking signals, though it is a possible approach.

Comment: Fantastic! I only derived the second model from qitemproxymodel and edit it a little bit! thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

QTableModel dataChanged is defined as Signal, not slot, so you can not connect signal to signal....

therefore this is not valid

```
QObject::connect(a, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), b, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));
```

and is not going to work

Comment: Signal can be connected to another signal